# Monitoring the performance of ML model on EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker, production

If we go back and use dockerized ML models on EC2 Instances - is there any native way to check the model metrics (for classification, for example, accuracy, precision, recall and f1-score)? For sure, Cloudwatch can be used but it will just gives the overall info regarding endpoint, disk utilisation, etc., but not ML model metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using SageMaker Model Monitoring for [Model Quality](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-monitor-model-quality.html) It provides the ML metrics you are interested in like recall, precision, f1,f2 and [more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-monitor-model-quality-metrics.html).